# How to filter a list using a function which returns Mono<Boolean> in Java?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a list of String.

For example:

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>(List.of("q1", "q2", "q3"));
```

I want to filter this list using a function that returns `Mono<Boolean>`. How do I do that?

function:

```
public Mono<Boolean> checkIfIdExists(String id)
{
  //External call
}
```

Comment: What's the condition for the filter?

Comment: @WJS I have updated the query. The condition is that if the function 'checkIfIdExists' returns false, I want to keep that id.

Comment: Have you considered using java streams?

Comment: @ShaanK I couldn't find any function in Streams that takes a Mono<Boolean>.

Comment: @ShaanK You can't use standard Java streams here as you can't filter() on a function that returns Mono<Boolean> rather than boolean. You have to use `filterWhen()` for that (only available in the project reactor publishers.)

Comment: Oh ok thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to create a `Flux` from your `List` then use `filterWhen()` on that:

`Flux.fromIterable(ids).filterWhen(id -> !checkIfIdExists(id)).collectList()`

(Note this will of course give you a `Mono<List<String>>` rather than a `List<String>`, as since your filter is reactive, the final result will be reative also. If you're not working reactively but just using a reactive library, you can just call `block()` to get the actual result.)

Comment: You cannot use '!' with a method returning Mono<Boolean>. Otherwise, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will implement it using Flux:

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>(List.of("q1", "q2", "q3"));

public Mono<Boolean> checkIfIdExists(String id)
{
    return Flux.fromStream(ids.stream())
               .filter(anId -> anId.equals(id))
               .hasElements();
}
```